# Cannot implicitly convert type. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics

I am trying to develop a web application using ASP.Net Web API. Now after creating Product model and IProductRepository interface I'm having difficulty in showing all products. I'm getting error message

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.Product>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Product>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
>
> Controllers\ProductsController.cs 17  20  WebApplication1

on this line of code

`return repo.GetAll();`

I don't understand what to do. If someone points out the problem and explain me what I'm doing wrong that would be very helpful.

**ProductsController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        static readonly IProductRepository repo = new ProductRepository();

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return repo.GetAll();
        }
    }
}
```

**ProductRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        public string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MediaSoftAppEntities"].ConnectionString;

        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll()
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            string sql = String.Format("Select [ProductID], [ProductName], [Price] FROM [Products]");

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs)){
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)){
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while(dr.Read()){
                        Product product = new Product();
                        product.ProductID = dr.GetInt32(0);
                        product.ProductName = dr.GetString(1);
                        product.Price = dr.GetInt32(2);
                    }
                }
            }
            return products.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

**IProductRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> GetAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: As the error states, I think you have two classes with the same name Product. Check the entire project whether you have two classes with the same name.

Comment: Yup; what @KiranHegde says. Perhaps you have a partial declaration somewhere, but it's got the wrong namespace?

Comment: The problem's solved, thanks to you. I wrongly added the ADO.Net entity Data Model in the root folder rather than in Model folder. So it auto generated 3 models in the root folder which I didn't notice. I manually added Product model so it raised the conflict. Now all working fine after deleting replicates and adding data models in model folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying that the compiler thinks that
`ProductsController.GetAllProducts` wants to return a `WebApplication1.Product`
but `IProductRepository.GetAll` returns a `WebApplication1.Models.Product` instead.

Do you have 2 `Product` classes in these 2 different namespaces?

Alternatively, maybe you previously had the `Product` class in the `WebApplication1` namespace, and it's now been moved into the `WebApplication1.Models` namespace, maybe you just have a stale reference and a "Rebuild All" will fix it.

Comment: The problem's solved, thanks to you. I wrongly added the ADO.Net entity Data Model in the root folder rather than in Model folder. So it auto generated 3 models in the root folder which I didn't notice. I manually added Product model so it raised the conflict. Now all working fine after deleting replicates and adding data models in model folder.